# React Native, result of date.getTime () is different in debug and normal mode

Tags: javascript, react-native

result of date.getTime () is different in debug and normal mode.

I know that the behavior of the web browser JS interpreter and React Native JSCore is different.

In the previous case I solved it by changing the empty space in the date string to T, but in this case T already exists.
So I don't know how to fix this.

```
const dateString = '2019-08-30T14:27:32';
const date = new Date(dateString);
console.log(date.getTime());

in debug
1567142852000
in normal
1567175252000
```

Comment: Timezone issue, try UTC setting instead, see Answers. You might have to adjust your time....

when you work with time on client side js you will always run into this timezone nonsense....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is due to JS processing the date in your local TimeZone. Use UTC all the time!**

The ECMAScript standard says [§15.9.1.1](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.9.1.1)

```
When using date.getTime();
"Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC."
```

You might want to try this:

```
var UTC=new Date(Date.UTC(year,month-1,day,0,0,0,0));
```

Or If you want use the string versino then append a `Z` to make it in UTC timezone

```
let date = new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z');
console.log(date.getTime());
```

if you really want to you could use a date js library such as

- [Date.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)

Comment: I thought it would be a simple process
There were a lot of unexpected problems, so I just used the library.